# How can I update my smart contract state when someone sell NFT to aother

Tags: tokens, nft, smart-contract-wallets, ethereum-classic

I implement **ERC1155**, in which if someone mints a token I save the **TokenId** and **Address** of the address that mint the token.

**mapping(uint256=>address) minter**

what I want to do when someone on **Opensea** sell NFT to another person I want to change the address of the previous owner address with the new owner address

do I need to override any method of **ERC1155**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be good if you're implementing 1155 correctly--there are functions there for transferring ownership.